# Local printers unusable after disconnecting from VPN

Tags: windows-10, vpn, network-printer

I'm on Windows 10.

I have a local network printer. Works fine. Then I connect to a VPN (Cisco Any Connect, if it matters)

After I disconnect from the VPN, the local printer won't work. It's listed as "offline", and toggling the online/offline does nothing, Windows 10 can't connect to it. Restarting the spooler service doesn't help.

The only thing that fixes the issue is a complete reboot of the system.

Comment: Is it possible that when you are one the VPN, something is forcing the "use printer offline" crap?  Also.. if by local, you mean at home.. I have my "network printer" hooked up via Wifi and USB at the same time.. I doubt the USB would fail./

Comment: By local I mean local Wifi, not USB. The printer doesn't go to the state "Use Printer Offline". In the list of printers, there's a gray "offline" message. Turning the "Use Printer Offline" option on & off doesn't do anything.

Comment: Disgusting fix.. but have you tried deleting and re-adding the printer?  If it works, you can automate this step and it will only take your computer a few seconds to do.

Comment: @Senor CMasMas: tried it, but simply setting up a new printer using the same port doesn't work. I can do it from scratch using the Canon install program, and it works, but it requires physically going to the printer to put it into new connection mode, then using a web installer from Canon that takes about 10-15 minutes to complete. It's got to be some weird combination of the Cisco VPN and Canon printer's network implementation. Other networked printers and other VPN's have not caused this problem.

Answer (score 1):

As a work-around you can either restart your PC (not great) or restart the printer spooling service

1. GUI

   - Run `SERVICES.MSC`
   - Scroll down to `Print Spooler` and choose `Restart the service`
2. Powershell

   - Start a Powershell instance as Administrator
   - `Restart-Service -Name "Spooler"`
3. CMD

   - Start a `CMD` instance as Administrator
   - `NET STOP SPOOLER`
   - `NET START SPOOLER`

Answer (score 0):

The fix is ipconfig /release
This is happening because your ip address is getting Carried from one network to the other network. which will not allow you to print. The only way to fix this is by restarting your pc (which will restart your network), changing the network configuration to a different configuration for example 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.2.1. or A different network class.

However, the easiest fix is to go to cmd on your windows search and type in the following command ipconfig /release. This will restart your network. and allow you to print again

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. I use Microsoft's built-in vpn.
I found out that if both the local network and the network I logged in to via vpn had the same IP address (eg 192.168.1.x), then I could not print to my local printer. When I changed my local network address to 192.168.2.x, I no longer had the problem. I hope this can help someone!