# Online printer stays "offline" after disconnecting Ciscoanyconnect VPN

Tags: vpn, printing, printer, windows-11, cisco-anyconnect

I'm on Windows 11. I can't connect to online printer after disconnecting from CiscoAnyConnect VPN. The situation stays the same after rebooting. I tried the cmd "ipconfig /release" which was shown in another question, [Local printers unusable after disconnecting from VPN](https://superuser.com/questions/1575855/local-printers-unusable-after-disconnecting-from-vpn).
Now I can't print at all and I'm in a trouble. Could anyone help me please.

Comment: I would check the Cisco Any Connect for a Windows 11 compliant update. Same thing for printers. Uninstall Any Connect. Remove printers.  Restart the Windows 11 machine (I use Windows 11). Install the printer and make sure it works. Then install Any Connect.  Any better?

Comment: Can you connect again to the VPN and check the printer ?

Comment: Can you access internet in general after disconnecting VPN ?